# how to detect if new files are added on the SDcard (Android)

Tags: android, sdk

Anyone can help me on how to detect new files added in SDcard. that would notify the user that there is a new files added on your SDcard.

Comment: What have you researched?

Comment: Android is Linux base. If I'm not wrong, there is something called inotify to let you monitor modification of files. I'm not sure if it can monitor directory as well.

Comment: i had research about FileObserver class (inotify) ill try to implement this algo. hope ill do this correctly :) thanks for idea.

Answer (score 2):

See FileObserver class.  You can monitor for file creation, delete, etc.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: thank you for the link spartygw i really appreciate your help